# how to create folder on Google Drive using Google Drive SDK for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, google-drive-api

I am using  Google Drive SDK for iPhone and trying to upload Audio file in "TestAudio" folder.If "TestAudio" folder is not created at google drive then first create that folder and after that my audio should store to that folder only. Every thing is working gr8 except folder creation. can any buddy please help?

I am using below code for upload audio file.

```
GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = nil;

NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                           pathForResource:@"honey_bunny_new"
                           ofType:@"mp3"];

if (soundFilePath) {
    NSData *fileContent = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:soundFilePath];
    uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:fileContent MIMEType:@"audio/mpeg"];
}

self.driveFile.title = self.updatedTitle;
GTLQueryDrive *query = nil;
if (self.driveFile.identifier == nil || self.driveFile.identifier.length == 0) {
    // This is a new file, instantiate an insert query.
    query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:self.driveFile
                                        uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
} else {
    // This file already exists, instantiate an update query.
    query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesUpdateWithObject:self.driveFile
                                                  fileId:self.driveFile.identifier
                                        uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
}
UIAlertView *alert = [DrEditUtilities showLoadingMessageWithTitle:@"Saving file"
                                                         delegate:self];

[self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                          GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                                          NSError *error) {
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
if (error == nil) {
    self.driveFile = updatedFile;
    self.originalContent = [self.textView.text copy];
    self.updatedTitle = [updatedFile.title copy];
    [self toggleSaveButton];
    [self.delegate didUpdateFileWithIndex:self.fileIndex
                                    driveFile:self.driveFile];
    [self doneEditing:nil];
} else {
    NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
    [DrEditUtilities showErrorMessageWithTitle:@"Unable to save file"
                                           message:error.description
                                          delegate:self];
}
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your code to create a folder, but I was having the same problem with folder creation myself.  As you know, the mimeType must be "application/vnd.google-apps.folder".  I ran into assert failures if the NSData parameter to uploadParametersWithData was nil.  So I tried a zero length NSData object and that failed.  Using a 1 byte NSData object also failed.  The trick is to call queryForFilesUpdateWithObject with uploadParameters:nil.  Then the folder creation works fine.  I also discovered that the Objective-C code shown at the end of:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

is incorrect.  The file.parents should be as follows:

```
GTLDriveParentReference *parentRef = [GTLDriveParentReference object];
parentRef.identifier = parentID;
if (parentID.length>0) file.parents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:parentRef,nil];
```