# How to create a folder in Google Drive using objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-drive-api

I need to create a folder in google drive . Please give me an idea how to create a folder . I referred the following link to create folder .
[how to create folder on Google Drive using Google Drive SDK for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873366/how-to-create-folder-on-google-drive-using-google-drive-sdk-for-iphone)

But no use . Please help me how to create a folder .

Comment: Did you checked [these Google links](https://www.google.fr/search?q=ios+create+a+folder+in+google+drive&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Zzj7U-yvCMvI8ge64oDIDA) ? What have you already tried ?

Comment: @Erzékiel Thanks for the link .Small mistake in my code. It worked for me . Here i'm posting my answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  GTLDriveFile *folderObj = [GTLDriveFile object];
        folderObj.title = tempString;
        folderObj.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

        // To create a folder in a specific parent folder, specify the identifier
        // of the parent:
        // _resourceId is the identifier from the parent folder
        if (driveFilesId.length && ![driveFilesId isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
            GTLDriveParentReference *parentRef = [GTLDriveParentReference object];
            parentRef.identifier = driveFilesId;
            folderObj.parents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:parentRef];
        }

        GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:folderObj uploadParameters:nil];
        GTLServiceTicket *queryTicket =
        [[DriveHelperClass getSharedInstance].driveService executeQuery:query
            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object,
                                NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DropboxCreateFolderSuccess" object:self userInfo:nil];
                    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                    [self viewWillAppear:YES];
                    [tbDownload reloadData];                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"error %@",error);
                }
            }];
```

Answer (score 0):

> For Creating folder Call below give function and pass the folder name,GTLServiceDrive object and parent id as parameters

```
+(void)createFolderName:(NSString *)folderName wihDriverservice:(GTLServiceDrive *)driveService OfParent:(NSString *)parentId WithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(GTLDriveFile *, NSError*))completionBlock{

GTLDriveParentReference *parent = [GTLDriveParentReference object];
parent.identifier = parentId;

GTLDriveFile *folder = [GTLDriveFile object];
folder.title =folderName;
folder.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
folder.parents = @[parent];

GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:folder uploadParameters:nil];
[driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                             GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                             NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Created folder");
        completionBlock(updatedFile, nil);

    } else {
        completionBlock(nil, error);
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

}